# What type of pike/spear is listed as it's own thing in the PHB?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

After searching what defines many of the kinds of [weapons in the PHB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#Weapons), I have found that the definition of [pike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/pike) and [spear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/spear) tends to be a placeholder for "pointed polearm" with their size being the only difference between the two. As defined, a pike would include all heavy pointed sticks unable to be thrown (such as halberds, glaives, etc) and spears would be any polearm that keeps the ability to be thrown (such as trident and arguably javelin).

That said, there are still many kinds of pikes and spears left unlisted in the PHB, leaving the definition, to me, as broad as saying "single-handed sword" or "two-handed sword."

What I would like to know from the community is if there are any specified differences, such as tip shape or size, that would single these out as "a pike" or "a spear"? Or is this liberty left specifically to the player's imagination?

Comment: Is the core of your question how to represent the ranseur in 5e's weapon system? If so, most of your question seems like filler.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question isn't about the 5e RPG, but actually about real-world definitions.

Comment: The original question, at least in the title, was: "Understanding polearms: What is the difference between a pike, a ranseur, and a spear?", which I felt includes: "what is the difference between a pike and a spear" and is the question I tried to answer.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil With the PHB not giving many details, why wouldn't someone do a quick google search to find out what the weapons listed are?  Are you suggesting this site be used to spellcheck the PHB?

Comment: @Everyone: The root meanings of "Pike" and "Spear", as far as I read, are common words for "pointed stick" with size as a difference, meaning that all pointed polearms fall in either category. As a comparison, it would be like saying "single-handed sword" and "two-handed sword", while listing all the options separately. My question was to a) understand which specific pike and spear the PHB was referring to and b) see if a ranseur would be classified as either. Thus, a definition and differentiation of all three would have been the answer I sought. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused here. I thought you were asking if the Pike/Spear represented a specific polearm amongst the many.  This seems to be meshing your questions together again. If you ultimately want to know what a ranseur is...ask that.

Comment: @NautArch I'm sorry if I am writing confusingly. I'm still a little flustered myself and trying to ask "about the 5e RPG" and avoid "real-world definitions." What I am trying to ask is "What kind of pike is listed as a pike" and "What kind of spear is listed as a spear", but I keep second-guessing myself. I'd love some help clarifying. (I realize that knowing that could answer the ranseur question so I'm avoiding that aspect and will ask later if needed)

Comment: It's not a problem, but it still feels like you just want to know about the ranseur. If that *is* the ultimate question, then that's your question. Everything else is just noise. I'd be less concerned about realworld definitions as 5e isn't simulationist and more concerned about what problem you're trying to solve for yourself.

Comment: I apologize for that. My intent is actually the opposite. I was using the ranseur to segue a clearer understanding of the items pike and spear, rather than focusing on ranseur. I realize I'm not the best wordsmith and I find that when I ask for clarifications beyond the book, I tend to get responses that quote the book, tell me to ask my DM, and many downvotes and "on hold" statuses, and I am trying to ask my questions better to avoid that. As for real-world, I'm also avoiding asking what a glaive is by googling it, leading to real-world comparisons.

Comment: Gotcha - then I think you need to focus on *why* you need to know about the pike and spear. What are you trying to understand and why is it important mechanically? And what we do here is answer by quoting from the sources - so getting those answers are what you should expect :) But if you're asking about Pike vs Spear, then what you'll get are the book quotations about the mechanical differences because that's where 5e lives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91267/discussion-between-victor-b-and-nautarch).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### There are several differences between a Pike and a Spear in D&D 5e.

1. A pike has the *two-handed* property, while a spear has the *versatile* property.  This means that a spear can be wielded with one or two hands, while a pike must be wielded with 2 hands.
2. A pike has the *heavy* property, which means that small characters like Halflings or Gnomes have disadvantage on attack rolls with the pike.
3. A spear has the *thrown* property (20/60).  This means that a spear can be thrown at a target up to 20 feet away, or 60 feet away with disadvantage.  Attempting to throw a pike would treat the pike as an [improvised weapon](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_SRD:Improvised_Weapons).
4. A pike deals 1d10 piercing damage, while a spear deals 1d6 piercing damage if wielded with one hand, or 1d8 piercing damage if wielded with 2 hands.
5. A pike has the *reach* property, which means that it can be used to make melee attacks against targets up to 10 feet away from the wielder.  A spear can only make melee attacks against targets within 5 feet of the wielder.
6. A pike is a martial weapon, while a spear is a simple weapon.  This means that many more classes gain proficiency with the spear than the pike.

### So what about the Ranseur?

A ranseur is not an official weapon in D&D 5e, as it is not listed in the weapons table in the Player's Handbook (as seen [here](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_SRD:Weapons)).  It would be up to the Dungeon Master to decide whether a ranseur would use a spear's statistics, a pike's, or if it warranted creating a new custom weapon with its own statistics.  If I were the Dungeon Master, I would simply rule that the ranseur would use the same statistics as the spear.

Comment: I tried to clarify OP's question, but haven't yet gotten confirmation this was acceptable. It was a fairly material change and you may want to adjust your answer (although it still generally answers it.)